# basic HTTP authentication preventing user adding bookmark

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, basic-authentication

I have a resource for `coffeeshops` where I allow the user to both `favorite` and `bookmark` individual coffee shops.

I also have `http_basic_authenticate_with`on the coffeeshop controller to prevent anyone but me from writing to my db.

It seems my current setup then doesn't allow users to actually `favorite` or `bookmark` unless they sign in.

How can I get around this? I am also using Devise for user management, can I take advantage of that to restrict write access to the database allowing me to remove `http_basic_authenticate_with`?

*coffeeshop_controller.rb*

```
class CoffeeshopsController < ApplicationController
http_basic_authenticate_with name: "*******, password: "*******", except: [:index, :show]
```

I tried updating this to `[:index, :show, :put]` but that has not made a difference.

Comment: If you have a user account system in place, e.g. with Devise, then you probably don't need any http_basic_authentication at all. [Read the README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers), and authenticate with a `before_filter`.

Comment: Yeah, I need to put aside some time and read about setting up roles I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `except` you should list the controller actions and not http methods, so something like the following:

```
class CoffeeshopsController < ApplicationController
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "*******", password: "*******", except: [:index, :favorite, :bookmark]
  def index
    # list of coffeeshops without authentication
  end

  def new
    # requires authentication
  end

  def create
    # requires authentication
  end

  def favorite
    # endpoint to mark coffeeshop as favourite without authentication
  end

  def bookmark
    # endpoint to bookmark a coffeeshop without authentication
  end
  ...
end
```